# Fading or Removing Boundaries in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography, transparency-opacity

I have a dot density map of a county. I need to either fade or remove the tract lines. I can adjust the frame transparency but that's not what I'm after.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: What application are you using?  What is the tack lines feature type?  Polyline, polygon, raster?

Comment: Sorry, I left out a lot of info. Arcmap 10.2. Polygons.

Comment: perhaps dissolve the polygons together, within symbology you can also select "no color" for the border

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps dissolve the polygons together. Another option: within symbology you can select "no color" for the border of the polygons.

Comment: Depending on whether there is a separate county layer already present and if it needs to be shown, the Dissolve isn't needed. The key to the answer is turning off the outlines of the tract layer which the dots are based off of. You could dissolve to county and sum the attribute the dots are based off of, but then the dots in the dissolved shape would be completely random and not represent the density based on tract distribution. Generally with a dot density map you need to hide borders of the dot data level and only show those borders one level up.

Comment: @ChrisW I think that's what Maksim said (that you could use Dissolve OR change the symbology) but the sentence was a little off, I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Indeed, I wasnt sure of what the final output was intended to look like. So yes, OR was meant to be included.

Comment: @DanC and Maksim - I guess the main thrust of my comment is that if you dissolve and do your dots on the dissolved shape, they will *not* produce the same representation of dots and could therefore *drastically* alter the output of the map. Getting/showing a single county border with a dissolve is one thing and may be needed (which I noted) and so dissolve would be a good way to do that. But in terms of eliminating the tract boundaries from the dot map (root of original question), you would definitely not want to dissolve.